Reached heap limit Allocation failed - Javascript heap out of memory, even though my laptop has 32GB RAM
I just bought a new device for better work performance, and tried to run my project on it. It is an angular project that uses angular 11, and in my old laptop normally I have to set max old space size to 8GB from 4GB so it can run. I tried it on my new laptop, but received the same message. I tried to set the max size to 16GB, same thing.
Generating browser application bundles (phase: building)...
<--- Last few GCs --->

[14740:000001E98859B110]   125607 ms: Mark-sweep 3975.7 (4135.4) -> 3963.7 (4139.1) MB, 1093.7 / 0.1 ms  (average mu = 0.491, current mu = 0.203) allocation failure scavenge might not succeed
[14740:000001E98859B110]   127648 ms: Mark-sweep 3980.6 (4139.4) -> 3969.4 (4144.1) MB, 1976.7 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.267, current mu = 0.032) allocation failure scavenge might not succeed


<--- JS stacktrace --->

FATAL ERROR: Reached heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
 1: 00007FF69A2F7B7F v8::internal::CodeObjectRegistry::~CodeObjectRegistry+114079
 2: 00007FF69A284546 DSA_meth_get_flags+65542
 3: 00007FF69A2853FD node::OnFatalError+301
 4: 00007FF69ABBB29E v8::Isolate::ReportExternalAllocationLimitReached+94
 5: 00007FF69ABA587D v8::SharedArrayBuffer::Externalize+781
 6: 00007FF69AA48C4C v8::internal::Heap::EphemeronKeyWriteBarrierFromCode+1468
 7: 00007FF69AA45D64 v8::internal::Heap::CollectGarbage+4244
 8: 00007FF69AA436E0 v8::internal::Heap::AllocateExternalBackingStore+2000
 9: 00007FF69AA68266 v8::internal::Factory::NewFillerObject+214
10: 00007FF69A79A735 v8::internal::DateCache::Weekday+1797
11: 00007FF69AC48F91 v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap+494417
12: 000001E98AC24E95

I think it supposed to run smoothly due to the specs of the device, and tried searching for solutions but can't find anything.

Please provide details as to which code causes the error to occur(or which steps others might need to take to reproduce the issue) and sample data for others to point you in the right direction.

Looks like you have an infinite loop, not a memory problem.

@Eliseo it seems so, is there any reference to solve it?

@YoshiMbele edited to add the error code

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Solved.
I have to settle with using
node --max_old_space_size=8192 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng serve
directly on command line. For now this will have to do. Thanks to all who chimed in for solutions
